# Replacements for "though"

Tags: word-usage

Examples:

> Mary thought the man was nice-looking. It wasn't enough to lower her
>   defenses, **though.**
>
> Tom crossed his arms on the table. He did it so hard, **though**, he
>   hurt his elbows.
>
> Sophie stopped finding meaning in things. Not in a spiritual or philosophical way, **though**; things simply ceased to make sense to her.

In what other way can I convey the same meaning without using the word *though*?

Comment: Just leave out the word "though" in every case you have written so far.

Comment: how about *however*? It can be a drop-in replacement in 1 and 3. In 2. it probably needs a *however, **that** he...*

Comment: Jano: Agreed with @OldCat.  What are you trying to convey with all the "though"s? How do you feel about the sentences with them removed? Do you feel they lack something, then (and if so, what)?

Comment: Or delete all the *thoughs* and start the clauses they follow with *buts*.

Comment: @Dan Bron Well, for example in number 3, I feel something's lacking if I remove the 'though.' I feel like the 'though 'is connecting the sentence with the first one. Like saying: "Sophie stopped finding meaning in things **but** not in a spiritual way..."

Comment: For me, eliding the "*though*" in #3 still leaves a heavy, pregnant pause at the semicolon, lending the same weight (or more) to the subsequent clause. As for #2, I'd actually *prefer* the sentence *without* the "*though*", and in #1, you could (as StoneyB says) remove the "*though*" and start the 2nd sentence with a "*But*", or simply replace the "*though*" with a "*however*" (which I think feels more natural). In any case, this isn't just a matter of finding stand-ins for "*though*"; you should consider modifications the sentences structures from the top down.

Comment: Aside from any issue with *though*, sentence 3 isn't right.  Perhaps consider  “Sophie stopped finding meanings in things, and not just spiritually or philosophically; they simply no longer made sense to her.”

Comment: @jwpat7 Thanks. You mean because "stopping finding meanings in things" is a "verb", so I should use adverbs?

Comment: No, I meant that the original sentence suggests the paradoxical case where spiritually and philosophically, things still make sense, but things no longer make sense.

Comment: I think that you can read the third example as not being inherently paradoxical if you take as its focus the arbitrary and inexplicable nature of Sophie's no longer finding meaning in things: By this interpretation, she stopped finding such meaning not because of a spiritual or philosophical crisis of some kind, but simply because the motives and impulses behind everyday actions ceased to make sense to her. In that case, the negative explanation "Not in a spiritual or philosophical way" doesn't contradict the central point about the sudden opacity (to Sophie's mind) of "things."

Comment: @SvenYargs, yes, one could so read it; but if that were the intended meaning, it would be better to say so more directly, and lucidly rather than opaquely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you feel that each of these sentences needs a transition word, you can use three different ones appropriately enough:

> Mary thought the man was nice-looking. **Nevertheless**, that wasn't enough to lower her defenses.
>
> Tom crossed his arms on the table. **Unfortunately**, he did it so hard that he hurt his elbows.
>
> Sophie stopped finding meaning in things. Not in a spiritual or philosophical way, **however**; things simply ceased to make sense to her.

The most suitable transition word in a particular instance depends on the context in which it is to appear. But there are many ways to move things along without depending overmuch on *though* and *although*—and often multiple options are available to you that will do the job equally well.

Answer (score 2):

Mary thought the man was nice-looking, **but** that wasn't enough to lower her defenses.

Tom crossed his arms on the table. He did it so hard **that** he hurt his elbows.

Sophie stopped finding meaning in things. Not in a spiritual or philosophical way; things simply ceased to make sense to her.